# How to use additional types for extra type safety in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm new to Haskell, and enjoying myself immensely.

As an exercise, I've written a program which tinkers with dates and times. In particular, I'm doing calculations involving minutes, seconds, and microseconds. Now I'm finding, while debugging, that I have a lot of errors where, for example, I'm adding minutes to seconds without multiplying by 60.

In order to move the debugging from run time to compile time, it occurred to me that I could use "type synonyms plus polymorphic functions" do something like this:

```
module Main where
type SecX = Integer
toMin :: SecX -> MinX
toMin m = div m 60
type MinX = Integer
toSec :: MinX -> SecX
toSec = (60 *)
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = 20 :: MinX
  let y = 20 :: SecX
  let z = x + y       -- should not compile
  print [x,y,z]
```

but this approach gives me two problems:

1. The line marked "should not compile" does in fact compile, and then proceeds to add 20 minutes to 20 seconds to give 40 somethings
2. When I add a further type of MuSecX for microseconds, I can't compile additional instances of toMin and toSec:

```
    type MuSecX = Integer  
    toSec :: MuSecX -> SecX  
    toSec m = div m 1000000  
    toMin :: MuSecX -> MinX  
    toMin m = div m 60000000
```

I'm obviously on the wrong path here. I'm sure I'm not the first to try to do something like this, so can anyone help, preferably with a "Canonical Haskell Way"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Type synonyms won't protect you from mixing types, that's not what they're for. They are literally just different names for the same types. They are used for convenience and/or for documentation. But `SecX` and `Integer` are still the very same type.

In order to create a completely new type, use `newtype`:

```
newtype SecX = SecX Integer
```

As you can see, the type now has a constructor, which can be used to construct new values of the type, as well as to get the `Integer` out of them by pattern-matching:

```
let x = SecX 20 
let (SecX a) = x  -- here, a == 20
```

Similar with `MinX`:

```
newtype MinX = MinX Integer
```

And the conversion functions would look like this:

```
toMin :: SecX -> MinX
toMin (SecX m) = MinX $ div m 60

toSec :: MinX -> SecX
toSec (MinX m) = SecX $ 60 * m
```

And now the line indeed won't compile

```
let x = MinX 20
let y = SecX 20 
let z = x + y       -- does not compile
```

But wait! This also doesn't compile anymore:

```
let sec1 = SecX 20
let sec2 = SecX 20 
let sec3 = sec1 + sec2       -- does not compile either
```

What's going on? Well, `sec1` and `sec2` are no longer just `Integer`s (which was the whole point of the exercise), and so the function `(+)` is not defined for them.

But you can define it: function `(+)` comes from the [type class `Num`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.5/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#t:Num), so in order for `SecX` to support this function, `SecX` needs to have an instance of `Num` as well:

```
instance Num SecX where
    (SecX a) + (SecX b) = SecX $ a + b
    (SecX a) * (SecX b) = SecX $ a * b
    abs (SecX a) = ...
    signum (SecX a) = ...
    fromInteger i = ...
    negate (SecX a) = ...
```

Wow, that's a lot to implement! Plus, what does it even mean to multiply seconds? That's a bit awkward, isn't it? Well, this is because the class `Num` is literally for *numbers*. It's expected that its instances really behave like numbers. It doesn't quite make sense for seconds, since although you can add them, other operations don't really make a lot of sense.

A better thing to implement for seconds is [`Semigroup`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.5/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup) (or perhaps even [`Monoid`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.5/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#t:Monoid)). Semigroup has a single operation `<>`, whose semantics is "*glue two of these things together and get another one of the same kind of thing in return*", which works very well for seconds:

```
instance Semigroup SecX where
    (SecX a) <> (SecX b) = SecX $ a + b
```

And now this will compile:

```
let sec1 = SecX 20
let sec2 = SecX 20 
let sec3 = sec1 <> sec2       -- compiles now, and sec3 == SecX 40
```

Similarly for minutes:

```
instance Semigroup MinX where
    (MinX a) <> (MinX b) = MinX $ a + b
```

---

But wait! We're still in trouble! Now `print [x, y, z]` doesn't compile anymore.

Well, first reason it doesn't compile is that the list `[x, y, z]` now contains elements of different types, which cannot happen. But ok, since it's just for testing, we can do `print x` and then `print y`, no matter.

But that *still* wouldn't compile, because the [function `print`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.5/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#v:print) requires that its argument has an instance of [class `Show`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-16.5/base-4.13.0.0/Prelude.html#t:Show) - that's where the function `show` lives, which is what is used to convert the value to string for printing.

And of course, we can implement that for our types:

```
class Show SecX where
    show (SecX a) = show a <> " seconds"

class Show MinX where
    show (MinX a) = show a <> " minutes"
```

Or, alternatively, we can have the compiler automatically *derive* the instances for us:

```
newtype SecX = SecX Integer deriving Show
newtype MinX = MinX Integer deriving Show
```

But in this case `show (SecX 42) == "SecX 42"` (or maybe just `"42"` depending on extensions enabled), whereas with my manual implementation above `show (SecX 42) == "42 seconds"`. Your call.

---

Phew! Now we can finally move on to the second question: conversion functions.

The usual, "base" approach is to just have different names for different functions:

```
minToSec :: MinX -> SecX
secToMin :: SecX -> MinX
minToMusec :: MinX -> MuSecX
secToMusec :: SecX -> MuSecX
... and so on
```

But if you really insist on keeping the same name for the functions, while having them work with different parameter types, that is possible too. More generally, this is called "overloading", and in Haskell the mechanism for creating overloaded functions is our old friend type class. Look above: we already defined function `(<>)` for different types. We can just make our own type class for this:

```
class TimeConversions a where
    toSec :: a -> SecX
    toMin :: a -> MinX
    toMuSec :: a -> MuSecX
```

And then add its implementations:

```
instance TimeConversions SecX where
    toSec = id
    toMin (SecX a) = MinX $ a `div` 60
    toMuSec (SecX a) = MuSecX $ a * 1000000
```

And similarly for minutes and microseconds.

Usage:

```
main = do
    let x = SecX 20
    let y = SecX 30
    let a = MinX 5
    let z = x <> y
    -- let u = x <> a  -- doesn't compile
    let v = x <> toSec a

    print [x, y, v]   -- ["20 seconds", "30 seconds", "320 seconds"]
    print a           -- "5 minutes"
    print (toMin x)   -- "0 minutes"
    print (toSec a)   -- "300 seconds"
```

---

Finally: don't use `Integer`, use `Int`. `Integer` is arbitrary precision, which means it's also slower. `Int` is 32- or 64-bit value (depending on the platform), which should be enough for your purposes I think.

But for a real implementation, I would actually suggest floating-point numbers in the first place (e.g. `Double`). This would make conversions fully reversible and lossless. With integers, `toMin (SecX 20) == MinX 0` - we just lost some information.

---

Comment: I see what you did there :-)

Comment: "Don't use `Integer`, use `Int`"  premature optimization something something dark side

Comment: Functional programming is a path to many abilities some consider to be unnatural :-)

Comment: @luqui Valid. However, in my particular case, I had bigger problems than my question implied. I had also dithered over Int v. Integer, and as a result, before I *cleaned up*, the program was larded with lots of toInteger and similar beasts, and, of course, a plethora of unnecessary parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

`type` is just a weak name alias. What you want is `newtype`:

```
module Main where

newtype SecX = SecX Integer deriving (Show)
newtype MinX = MinX Integer deriving (Show)

toMin :: SecX -> MinX
toMin (SecX s) = MinX $ s * 60

toSec :: MinX -> SecX
toSec (MinX m) = SecX $ m `div` 60

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = MinX 20
  let y = SecX 20
  print x
  print y
  --let z = x + y       -- will not compile
  --print [x,y,z]
```

Now the value is actually *wrapped* within the type, and the `Integer` part (and thus, e.g. `(+)`) is inaccessible directly. You're now free to provide all operations you might want that deal specifically with the wrapper - as it is, in fact, a new type.

`newtype` works just like `data`, but cannot have multiple members (can only "wrap" a value of one type), and is implemented to be efficiently shed during the optimization phase.

Comment: Thank you very much. Good answer, and helpful, but the green tick had to go to Fyodor.